# Express+Redis Post request not Stringify-ing

Tags: node.js, express, redis, postman

I'm working on a Redis API and I can make GET requests from it so I know it works, but when I try making a POST request to http://localhost:3001/history/additem the terminal returns this error:

`Error: node_redis: The HSET command contains a invalid argument type of "undefined". Only strings, dates and buffers are accepted. Please update your code to use valid argument types. OK`

I can only assume its a problem with stringify

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const connect = require('./Connection')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
const redis = require('redis')

const port = 3001

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    connect.createConnection().then(client => {
            res.send('Search Bar Contents')
            console.log(client);

    })

});




app.post('/history/addItem', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    connect.createConnection().then(client => {

        const history = JSON.stringify(req.body.history)
        const uuid = req.body.uuid

        client.hset(uuid, "history", history, redis.print)
        client.hgetall(uuid, (err, results) => {
            if(results){
                res.send(results)
            }else{
                res.send(err)
            }
        })
        client.quit((err, reply) => {
            if(!err){
                console.log(reply);
            }else{
                console.log(err);
            }
        })

    })
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

Also this is my first question on stackoverflow so if I could improve how I'm asking or formatting my question I would appreciate feedback on that

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```js
// ....
const history = JSON.stringify(req.body.history) ?? null;
// ....
client.hset(uuid, "history", history);
// ....
```

Because hset takes parameters as
`HSET key field value [field value ...]`
so parameters should be `odd` (key and field-value pairs)

Comment: ?? null returned a unexpected token when i tried starting the server, without redis.print i got this callback error 
```

TypeError: command_obj.callback is not a function

```

Comment: may be your nodejs version does not support ?? operator you can use || for ??

Comment: Sorry, you right, I forgot callback function for sync usage (I use generaly async usage with .then etc)

Comment: no worries, at least i learned it requires a callback :D